# How to make chapter*, section* and subsection* appear in the table of contents

Tags: latex

I need to produce a PDF document in which I need some "chapters" (along with its sections and subsections) to be non-numbered but still included in the ToC.

This is for my master thesis. I'm using the book document class, because I don't like memoir defaults.

If I use `\chapter*`, then LaTeX remove the chapter from the ToC. But I'm required to have those as well in the ToC. Furthermore, the headings (fancy) are not changed with `\chapter*`.

The overall structure of the thesis is:

```
\maketitle %% A custom one
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\chapter*{Abstract}
\chapter*{Introduction} %% This "chapter" presents the whole thesis

\mainmatter

%% Here the real chapters are written

\appendix
%% Appendixes here

%% bibliography
```

How can I make `\chapter*`, `\section*`, and `\subsection*` to appear in the ToC and to modify the headers?

I think I may be using some packages that interfere with the way headers and footers are generated. The answer of [smilingthax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483341/smilingthax) gets the first part of the question responded: I have now my \chapter*s on the TOC.

This is my full preamble:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,round,semicolon]{natbib}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
%% inputenc so we can write in spanish
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fixltx2e} % LaTeX patches, \textsubscript
\usepackage{cmap} % fix search and cut-and-paste in PDF
\usepackage{ifthen}
%% \usepackage{float} % float configuration
%% \floatplacement{figure}{TH} % place figures here definitely

%% fontenc so we can use TrueType fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{garamond}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%% Custom colors
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.95}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.2,0.95,0.2}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{0.95,0.2,0.2}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0,0,0.95}
\definecolor{ligthred}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}

\definecolor{shade}{HTML}{D4D7FE} %light blue shade

% Margins
\usepackage[left=0.9in,top=1in,right=0.7in,bottom=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks=true, citecolor=ligthred,
  urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\widowpenalty9000
\clubpenalty7000

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\bigrule}{\titlerule[0.5mm]}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Huge}
{\garamond
% DESCOMENTAR PARA SUBIR LOS CAPITULOS
\vspace{-1.125in} \titlerule \filleft
\Large\chaptertitlename\ \Large\thechapter}{0mm}
{\filleft}[\vspace{0.5mm} \bigrule]

\let\cite=\citep

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}  %% Clears all headers

% admonition (specially marked topic)
\providecommand{\DUadmonition}[2][class-arg]{%
  % try \DUadmonition#1{#2}:
  \ifcsname DUadmonition#1\endcsname%
    \csname DUadmonition#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \else
    \begin{center}
      \fbox{\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{#2}}
    \end{center}
  \fi
}

% title for topics, admonitions and sidebar
\providecommand*{\DUtitle}[2][class-arg]{%
  % call \DUtitle#1{#2} if it exists:
  \ifcsname DUtitle#1\endcsname%
    \csname DUtitle#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \else
    \smallskip\noindent\textbf{#2}\smallskip%
  \fi
}

% error admonition title
\providecommand*{\DUtitleerror}[1]{\DUtitle{\color{red}#1}}

% fieldlist environment
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\DUfieldlist}}{
  \newenvironment{DUfieldlist}%
    {\quote\description}
    {\enddescription\endquote}
}{}

% legend
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\DUlegend}}{
  \newenvironment{DUlegend}{\small}{}
}{}

%%% Fallback definitions for Docutils-specific commands
% numeric or symbol footnotes with hyperlinks
\providecommand*{\DUfootnotemark}[3]{%
  \hyperlink{#2}{\textsuperscript{#3}}\raisebox{1em}{\label{#1}}%
}

\providecommand{\DUfootnotetext}[4]{%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{%
    \protect\hyperlink{#2}{#3}}%
  \protect\raisebox{1em}{\protect\label{#1}}%
  \footnotetext{#4}%
  \endgroup%
}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newlength{\DUtablewidth} % internal use in tables


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bbding}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't think an specialized command exists for that. But you can use

```
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
```

to add it to the TOC. BTW, I didn't have problems with \chapter* and fancy, so I used:

```
\newcommand\chap[1]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
```

Comment: This works almost as expected. I have the chapters on the TOC, but headers are not updated. I have a \chap{Introduction}, but the pages of that chap get the "List of figure" header.

Comment: Try adding \chaptermark{#1} resp. \leftmark / \rightmark. See also: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Customising_with_fancyhdr

Comment: Thanks to all. I solved all my problems with \chaptermark and also with \phantomsection.

Answer (score 5):

Variations on this question have been asked and answered several times on the [TeX-specific sister site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/):

- [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35433)
- [`\tableofcontents` does not list the unnumbered chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129687)
- [How to use `\section*{something}` without removing it from the Table of Contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106480)
- [Redefine `\section*` so it behaves *exactly* as `\section` except leaves out the number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292408)
- ...

I'm going to copy over [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292419) to the last of those, because it demonstrates a different technique from any of the existing answers to this question: redefine `\section` so that the *only* effect of `\section*` is to skip printing the section numbers.  This will work even when sectioning commands are being issued from the guts of packages you don't control.

---

[...] Redefine `\section` to capture and condition on when the starred-version is used. Upon finding `\section*`, issue it just like you would `\section`, but remove the number-printing mechanism through an appropriate setting of the counter `secnumdepth`.

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an easy interface for (re)defining commands that may have a `s`tarred version, as well as an `o`ptional argument.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\newcounter{@secnumdepth}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\setcounter{@secnumdepth}{\value{secnumdepth}}% Store secnumdepth
     \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}% Print only up to \chapter numbers
     \oldsection{#3}% \section*
     \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{@secnumdepth}}}% Restore secnumdepth
    {\IfValueTF{#2}% \section
       {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
       {\oldsection{#3}}}% \section{..}
}
\makeatother
```

(To do the same thing to `\chapter`, `\subsection`, etc., search-and-replace `section` appropriately, and adjust the temporary value used for `secnumdepth`.)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it with smilingthax' answer and comments. As it didn't work to use only `\leftmark` or `\rightmark`, here is a command that you can use to (i) make a chapter non-numbered (ii) add it to the TOC and (iii) have a correct page header.

```
\newcommand\chap[1]{
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \markboth{#1}{#1}}
```

The same works for sections (and subsections respectively):

```
 \newcommand\secTOC[1]{
    \section*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    \markboth{#1}{#1}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it using the following:

```
\chapter*{Introduction} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
```

I have just added this line *\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}* after the *\chapter*{Introduction}*. Then I have written my writings of this chapter. Now it appears in the table of contents perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`

worked for me as a solution if you used the un-asterisk version of \chapter{} etc for the book class. Hyperref works as well if you wanted a linkable ToC along with my solution. Make sure to compile it twice to get it to work on both the ToC and inline.

Unfortunately however, your preamble killed my TexStudio attempt to check to see if it worked for your exact code, but I have faith.

Used TeXstudio 2.6.2 (SVN 4110M)
Using Qt Version 4.8.5, compiled with Qt 4.8.5 R
On Windows 7 64-bit